# What is the difference between processor (CPU) and microprocessor?

Tags: microprocessors

what is the difference between "processor (CPU)" and "microprocessor" in the sense of computer architecture? These terms confuse me.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The difference is purely historical. In the old days of lore, the CPU used to sit in a separate enclosure, like here:

[image: Processor (CPU) unit of a Vax 11/750]

A microprocessor is a particular implementation of processor which happens to fit in a single electronic component (chip) package:

[image: PowerPC 601 microprocessor]

Clearly, nowadays all processors are microprocessors, so the distinction is completely blurred.